# std::list remove_if using state in stack

Tags: c++, list, closures

I want to remove elements from a `std::list` with linear complexity (going through each element in the list only once). I need to do so depending on the value of a variable in the stack:

```
int somevalue= 5;
int count=0;
mylist.remove_if( 
    [](MyStructure* s)
    { 
        if (s->somefield==somevalue) 
        {
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    });
```

Of course, this doesn't work - `somevalue` is a variable in the stack.

I've tried using template functions, only to realize (after `illegal operation on bound member function expression`) you can't really use them in this situation. I know I need to make a closure somehow, so I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614170/c-closure-hack), but I can't use `C++0x` yet and I failed to adapt the other answer for my usecase, as I don't really understand if there's some magic to `operator`.

Alternatively, is there some way to remove an element from a list given the current position of an iterator (without going through the whole list again to find the element)?

Comment: `mylist.remove_if( [somevalue](MyStructure* s){ s->somefield==somevalue });`

Comment: You say you can't use C++11 features, but you're using a lambda expression? That's a C++11 feature.

Comment: @juanchopanza That seems to work, thanks! is it safe to use it to change the values of the closed over variables (see edit)?

Comment: @pdw My compiler complained when I tried to use `std::placeholders`, so I sort of assumed. Sorry for the confusion, I'm not very experienced in C++

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Iterate on the elements to identify which one you want to remove. Use [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) to remove the identified elements and continue to iterate from the returned iterator.

Something like that:

```
int somevalue=5;
std::list<MyStructure*> myList;
// ...
std::list<MyStructure*>::iterator it=myList.begin();
while(it!=myList.end())
{
  if ((*it)->somefield==somevalue)
  {
    it = myList.erase(it);
  }
  else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the lambda expression (a c++11 feature), you can capture the `somevalue` by value like this: `[somevalue](...) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

You must capture `somevalue` in your lamdba expression to use it:

**Example (live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff8d3b8050728211)) :**

```
struct MyStructure
{
    int somefield;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  std::list<MyStructure> my_list = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 1 }, { 3 }, { 2 }, { 1 } };
  int somevalue = 2;
  my_list.remove_if( [somevalue](MyStructure s){ return s.somefield == somevalue; });
  //                   ^^^^^^
  //                   Capture      

  for(auto& s : my_list)
      std::cout << s.somefield << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the variable in the sample code:

```
int somevalue= 5;
mylist.remove_if( [somevalue](MyStructure* s){ s->somefield==somevalue });
```

If no C++11 could be used you need to make the functor yourself:

```
// For static constant check
template <int CheckValue>
struct Equal {
    operator()(const MyStructure* s) { return s->somefield == CheckValue; }
};

mylist.remove_if(Equal<5>);

..or..

// For dynamic constant check as the sample code
struct Equal {
    Equal(int check_value) : m_check_value(check_value) {}
    operator()(const MyStructure* s) { return s->somefield == m_check_value; }
private:
    int m_check_value;
};

mylist.remove_if(Equal(somevalue));
```